# `yum upgrade git` centos

Tags: centos, git, yum, installation, rpm

I want to upgrade git cause the version on centos5 is 1.5.5.6. `yum upgrade git` says, "No Packages marked for Update." Am I using the wrong rpm? How do I use a different rpm? Which should I use?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779274/how-can-git-be-installed-on-centos-5-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without adding an additional external repository, you wont get a later version of git.

See this article for getting Git 1.7 via yum:

http://www.webtatic.com/packages/git17/