# How does one get a recent version of git installed on an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, git, package-management

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get `yum` to install a recent version of git on an ec2 instance. `yum install git` installs 1.7.4.5, which is not recent enough. Surely there's some 1.8.x package out there someplace so I don't have to attempt to build from source?

Incidentally, following the instructions here [`yum upgrade git` centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/214598/yum-upgrade-git-centos) leads to... 1.7.4.5.

Comment: Your uch more likely to get an answer to this on [SO].

Comment: I can never tell what's topical where these days. Apologies.

Comment: This isn't really a StackOverflow question, either.

Comment: @ceejayoz [SO]'s faq says they accept questions about software development tools.

Comment: i guess google search works faster :)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need a newer version of git? Or do you just think you want it because it has a bigger number?

Comment: ^^ what about bug fixes, new features and compatibility with other software?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain, because the authors of the Jenkins git plugin said so. I'm obviously not thrilled about the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page about git package:**
http://pkgs.org/centos-6/puias-computational-x86_64/git-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.x86_64.rpm.html

The git rpm installs the core tools with minimal dependencies. To
install all git packages, including tools for integrating with other SCMs, install the **git-all** meta-package.

**Download git package itself:**

Download git-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.x86_64.rpm for CentOS 6 from the PUIAS Computational repository.

```
$> rpm -ihv http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/computational/6/x86_64/git-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.x86_64.rpm
```

**or Download PUIAS computational Base:**

Download the latest puias-computational rpm from:

```
$> rpm -ihv http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/computational/6/x86_64/puias-computational-GPFS-6-1.puias6.8.noarch.rpm
```

and run:

```
$> yum install git
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why 20 minute of Googling couldn't have turned that up.

Comment: Although the installation instructions seem to be incomplete, so guess I'm installing from source anyway.

Comment: i gave you direct link to "how to".

Comment: Yep, I followed those instructions. There are four dependencies required to install that computational rpm that aren't in the package list.

Comment: please name these dependencies, probably you need to enable default repository like EPEL: rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Comment: Three of them were `puias-*` - one was definitely `puias-core`. I wouldn't think EPEL would have that.